# Is there a way to import JSON into Realm during migration?

Tags: android, realm

I use realm for my app and it's time to do the first data update during migration. Unfortunately there is no createAllFromJson on the DynamicRealm instance. is there a way to get the Realm or call createAllFromJson in another way?

Answer (score 0):

There is no utilities for that use cases. If you want to use JSON during migration, you should create some code for that.

Answer (score 0):

There didn't seem to be a way in the API, here is the best I was able to do:

```
    Realm.init(app);
    RealmConfiguration configuration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
        .schemaVersion(X)
        .migration((realm, oldVersion, newVersion) -> {
             // migration stuff
             realmReImportNeeded = true; // static bool false by default
        })
        .initialData(realm -> {
            importData(realm);
        })
        .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration);
    // Open immediately so migration is triggered
    try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
        if (realmReImportNeeded) {
            realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> importData(realm1));
        }
    }
```